# Question locked as collaborative effort does not allow editing of answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation, locked-posts

On the question [Converting String to Int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585779/4464702), I noticed this moderator notice:

> **locked** by [Matt ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) Feb 10 at 20:31
>
> This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*

This message implies that I am able to edit the answers on this question, right? The opposite is the case: The edit button is inaccessible, since the question is locked:

> This is a screenshot of the edit button being disabled on an answer:
>   [image: screenshot of tooltip]

This is the case for all answers in that question.

The opposite is the case on other questions under the same lock:

> This is a screenshot of the edit button being enabled on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/4464702) on another question that was closed for the same reason.
>   [image: screenshot]

Is this intentional? If yes, why is it this way? If not, can it please be corrected?

Comment: I'm able to click edit (though I am >2k so have [edit privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)). I tried it, and I could also add a comment.

Comment: Comments being disabled is intentional. The only think a wiki lock really allows is editing the answers. (Though it looks like it's only for 2k+ users- Never noticed that before, if that is the case.)

Comment: Actually, this is very strange. [The C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) doesn't have the "edit" button locked for me, and it has the same lock applied. I was also incorrect about comments- They're only supposed to be disabled on the question.

Comment: On closer inspection I cannot edit or comment on the *question*; the *answers* I can edit or comment on. See "[How can locked posts be editable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247746/284827)" on the main meta site. The *question* **is** locked; the *answers* are **not**.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Actually, the answer edit buttons are locked for me on the linked question, but the answer _comments_ aren't. So there is something odd going on there, it looks like.

Comment: @WaiHaLee For clarification: http://i.imgur.com/J8QhBrf.png while on other posts with the same lock the edit button is not disabled

Comment: I don't even know why is this locked in first place?

Comment: ***Status completed*** change: See [the duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387036/locked-post-says-contributors-should-edit-but-suggesting-edits-is-disabled-for/387711#387711).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That lock reason is supposed to be used for questions with just a few *community-wiki* answers - in other words, answers that [anyone with a nominal amount of rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) can edit without needing approval. [Stuff like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), where the answer is a collaborative effort built by many editors over the years.

That... was not the case here. It was just a question with a lot of repetitive answers, most of them never edited. I removed numerous answers that added nothing and unlocked the question (it will remain protected for obvious reasons).