# Locked post says contributors should edit, but suggesting edits is disabled for both the question and its answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-posts

[Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files) is locked:

[image: Lock notice]

The [linked help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) says locking prevents editing and contradicts the above banner, but I'm not sure if the banner is a template or free-text provided by that particular editor that added the lock. The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/159521/revisions) doesn't give any content, only `Locked` and the moderator and the timestamp. Of course, the site itself enforces what the help page says.

Question:
[image: Question is locked]

Answer:
[image: Answer is locked]

Should this locked post be editable? If not, can moderators change that message to be more accurate? If the discrepancy is the result of a policy change, how do we go about scouring the huge number of locked posts for issues like this one?

*Ancillary question: how do I view the list of meta questions that link to a non-meta post, such that I can search for duplicates before making a meta post? I'm new to meta and can't see an obvious way to go about this; why isn't there a "related posts" block for meta content like there is for other SE content?*

Comment: Yes, because its parent question is what was locked. That also prevents new answers and evidently editing existing answers.

Comment: That is actually a vague and misleading message. Regular users can edit answers to locked questions but **only if they have the full editing privileges**. We do not currently allow users to suggest edits to answers on locked questions. Although, I'm not entirely sure *why*.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense; thank you for the explanation! How difficult is it to change an error message or other behavior of Stack Overflow to make it more appropriate? I understand that it is not open-source, but is there an issue tracker or similar that we can contribute to?

Comment: @bburhans you've just done it = meta is the place (don't hold your hopes to high so - there is mostly miss and miss success rate on proposals for some time :)) . You may change this question to be "feature-request" instead of "support" to clarify that...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov will do, thanks! Does this also mean that the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) is incorrect, because it explicitly says editing should *not* be allowed? And the same for the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) that makes no mention of locked content?

Comment: That's so odd, @animuson ... the entire point of a CW is to let more people edit without needing to suggest edits. Do you know, is 100 enough or does it have to be the full 2k?

Comment: @bburhans The documentation isn't wrong. No one (other than moderators) can edit the *question*. The confusion here relates to the answers, which are not locked. What actually needs to change is the red edit warning should explain why editing is impossible and in what cases it is possible... "you need n reputation to edit answers to locked questions."

Comment: @Catija I'd say the documentation is ambiguous, at the very least. It simply says "locking prevents edits", although in context of the post, that does imply that only the question is locked. In this case, the question was converted to a community wiki, which presumably overrides the lock per the last full paragraph in https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts: `A "wiki" is a question whose answers can be edited by low-reputation users[...]`

Comment: However, you have to click through a link to [another help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) to see that "low-reputation" still means "100 rep or more." I'd like to clarify the diction in both articles, as they're needlessly vague and wouldn't get any more verbose or complex with a simple change to the wording. Do you agree?

Comment: A "post" in this case is only a single post, either a question or an answer. The only lock that locks the question and all its answers is a historical significance lock. The ambiguity is in that term which is often used to refer to complete Q&A posts but also as a general term that includes both questions and answers rather than saying "a question or answer that is locked...". The community wiki status is irrelevant to the answers being editable. All it changes is the reputation level of people able to directly edit rather than suggest an edit.

Comment: Regardless, as animuson already mentioned, blocking edit suggestions is odd and possibly unintentional. There's definitely places we can improve but at least a small part of the problem is related to this odd behavior. We need to either fix it or change the warning message (not the lock post notice) to be more clear.

Comment: For your last comment about searching for questions that link to non-meta posts: it is a bit of a gamble but [`url:/159521/`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%2F159521%2F) does work. In theory you could add stackoverflow.com in front but then you need to take all allowed routes into account: /q/ and /a/ and /questions/

Comment: Not sure what's ambiguous about: "**This question’s answers are a collaborative effort**. If you see something that can be improved, **just edit the answer to improve it! No additional answers can be added here**." emphasis on bold. It describe you can edit the answer even if the question was locked.

Comment: Yes, @Shinjo. It's perfectly clear. It's also wrong, as bburhans *cannot* edit the answers. Hence the question.

Comment: @TRiG Hence there is the continuation: **Read more about locked post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)** which explain why a low-rep user can't edit the answers. Emphasis on **When should a post be locked?** exception #2: which explain [low-rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki): Edit community wiki
Privilege type: Creation privilege

Awarded at: 100 reputation

Comment: @Shinjo So your argument is that the large banner on the page explaining that the post is locked but answers can be edited is just as clear as the text which is accessed by clicking the first link, going to paragraph 4, item 2, clicking on the link in there, being taken to the information on the  'edit community wiki' page which introduces the concept of privileges, community wikis and rep but makes no statement that without this privilege such actions are not possible despite advice to the contrary on the post itself? I'm not convinced they are equally clear.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Well noted. Why don't you propose alternative then? Since this was feature-request

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't get this error any more.

We talked about it internally and Shog did some digging and we can't really figure out why suggested edits on answers to locked questions were ever prevented (it's been this way since 2011!) so we've changed the settings so that suggested edits are allowed!

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!